# Is there any immigration visa for poor Iranians?

Tags: immigration, iran-citizens

Economy of Iran is under pressure. [30% of Iranian can not achieve a wealth meal per day](https://iraneconomist.com/fa/news/664776/%D9%81%D9%82%D8%B1-%D8%BA%D8%B0%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-30-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B5%D8%AF-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%85-%D8%B1%DA%98%DB%8C%D9%85-%D8%BA%D8%B0%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85-%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AF).
[image]
[image]
While many poor countries like African countries and south Asian countries traditionally are supported by First world countries like France, England, America for immigration but Iranians do not have such advantage.  Afghans also can ask for visa according to International humanitarian law from south american countries like Brazil. In last year just Germany did not fire Iranian asylum seeker (and that was for women, life, freedom movement). So is there any solution for this bottleneck? For example something such as advantages devoted to Afghans?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand the political situation.

Most industrialized nations will accept **refugees** who must flee from their home, but only if no other nation can be made to take the refugees. Most nations do not **want** refugees to come. Refugees must prove their reason for fleeing, and this is made very difficult for most of them.

Most industrialized nations will accept **immigrants** if the immigrant brings a benefit to the nation. If the immigrant is very rich and brings the money, that is a benefit for the nation, but mostly they are looking for **skilled workers** who are willing **fit into the society** of the nation.

Fitting in means learning the language and culture, and that is where historical ties from colonial times in the last century matter a little bit. But the key thing is skills, either with a degree from a university or with professional experience.

Comment: Based on the juradiction, the **right of asylum** is based on political persecution and not for economic reasons. [Article 16a (Right of asylum) Basic Law for the Federal Republic of Germany](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0089): *(1) Persons persecuted on **political grounds** shall have the right of asylum.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson, other laws are about wars and natural disasters. From the way the question was asked, I was aiming for a basic explanation.